# Is there a performance benefit to copying CUDA C __constant__ variables to local memory

Tags: c, optimization, cuda, constants, local

For example if you have a simple constant variable `__device__ __constant__ int MY_CONSTANT;` and it is accessed by the same kernel thread multiple times:

```
__global__ void move(int* dataA, int* dataB, int* dataC){
    ...
    dataB[threadID] = dataA[threadID] * MY_CONSTANT;
    dataC[threadID] = dataA[[threadID] * dataB[threadID] % MY_CONSTANT;
    ...
}
```

I can see that it would be beneficial to store the value of `dataA[threadID]` and `dataA[threadID] * MY_CONSTANT` in local variables/registers to avoid unnecessary global reads. Ignoring that, would it be beneficial to place the value of `MY_CONSTANT` in a local variable to avoid it being read twice, or would this be handled by the compiler, given that it cannot change, unlike the other global data.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know, for sure, is to code it up each way and do the following:

1. Generate and examine the PTX code to determine what the compiler emits for each implementation.
2. Instrument and profile each implementation and test performance using representative inputs.

What you're asking about is the sort of micro-optimization that warranted the phrase "premature optimization". My recommendation is that you forget about such kinds of optimization unless you find that performance is insufficient for your needs.

That being said, constant memory is stored in global memory space, and when accessed by a multiprocessor, becomes added to the cache. Subsequent accesses to this area of memory have much lower latency. When all threads in a warp access the same word of constant memory, there are no conflicts and everything happens rather quickly anyway (note that hardware differs a lot, and what I'm saying maybe isn't technically accurate for your device, but the takeaway is this: follow the access patterns for memory types, and you won't need to worry about the kind of thing you're asking here).

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try. I'm suspecting that it will make little difference with the above example, but it may do with a more complex kernel if the cache were to be used a lot more.